# Changing number of index in DataFrame?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, calendar, dataframe

i am trying to change the output of the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel, bdate_range, DatetimeIndex, date_range
from pandas.tseries.holiday import get_calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz as pytz
from pytz import timezone

start =  datetime(2013, 1, 1)

hr1 = np.loadtxt("Spot_2013_Hour1.txt")

index = date_range(start, end = '2013-12-31', freq='B')
Allhrs = Series(index)
Allhrs = DataFrame({'hr1': hr1})
df = Allhrs
indexed_df = df.set_index(index)
print indexed_df
```

The error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-61-c7890d8ccb07>", line 17, in <module>
    indexed_df = df.set_index(index)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2390, in set_index
    frame.index = index

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1849, in __setattr__
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

  File "properties.pyx", line 65, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas/lib.c:38491)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 400, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1965, in set_axis
    'new values have %d elements' % (old_len, new_len))

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 365 elements, new values have 261 elements
```

The problem:

I have a time series which i load from a txt file. The time series consists of 365 elements, i.e. all days of the year 2013. I need this txt file as it is because i need to analyse each day.

Additionally i need to analyse specific days of the year 2013. So i want to change the reading of the data, i.e. i want to see only business days. Additionally it would be great to see/print specific days.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a DataFrame (or Series) with *all the days* of the year:

```
index = date_range(start='2013-1-1', end='2013-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(hr1, index=index)
```

Next, use `df.asfreq('B')` to downsample `df` to business days:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# hr1 = np.loadtxt("Spot_2013_Hour1.txt")
hr1 = np.random.random(365)
index = date_range(start='2013-1-1', end='2013-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(hr1, index=index)

indexed_df = df.asfreq('B')
print(indexed_df)
```

---

To set the frequency to business days while excluding certain days, you could use [`offsets.CustomBusinessDay`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental):

```
import pandas.tseries.offsets as offsets
holidays = ['2013-10-03' , '2013-12-25']
business_days = offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays)
custom_df = df.asfreq(business_days)
```

Thus, `custom_df` has two days fewer than `indexed_df`

```
In [12]: len(custom_df)
Out[12]: 259

In [13]: len(indexed_df)
Out[13]: 261
```

and "holidays" like `'2013-10-03'` are missing:

```
In [18]: '2013-10-03' in indexed_df.index
Out[18]: True

In [19]: '2013-10-03' in custom_df.index
Out[19]: False
```

It's also useful to know that [the `reindex` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) can be used to subselect rows. For example, you can subtract specific days from `indexed_df.index`:

```
idx = indexed_df.index - pd.DatetimeIndex(holidays)
custom_df2 = df.reindex(idx)
```

The result, `custom_df2` is equal to `custom_df`:

```
In [35]: custom_df2.equals(custom_df)
Out[35]: True
```

but note that the indexes are a bit different:

```
In [36]: custom_df.index
Out[36]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01, ..., 2013-12-31]
Length: 259, Freq: C, Timezone: None

In [37]: custom_df2.index
Out[37]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01, ..., 2013-12-31]
Length: 259, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

The `custom_df` as `Freq: C`, while `custom_df2` has `Freq: None`. The `freq` is used by certain methods, such as `snap` and `to_period`. But these methods also allow you to specify the desired frequency as an argument, so in practice I have not found this difference to be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I have one additional question: how to exclude specific days from the time series, say: 2013.10.03 and 2013.12.25 ?

Comment: I've added some information on how to exclude specific days using [`CustomBusinessDay`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental) and (alternatively) by calling [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).